# Collection Pagination Fails After plone.app.contenttypes Enabled

Tags: plone

Environment: Plone 4.3.4 Unified Installer

I add a collection named 'list', assigning Item Count to '2'.

[image: collection configuration]

And pagination works fine as expected.

[image: pagination #1]

[image: pagination #2]

Then, I edit develop.cfg to include plone.app.contenttypes:

```
[sources]
plone.app.contenttypes = git git@github.com:plone/plone.app.contenttypes.git branch=1.1.x

[buildout]
eggs +=
    plone.app.contenttypes

[versions]
plone.app.event = 1.1.4
```

Run bin/buildout -c develop.cfg and activate the plone.app.contenttypes add-on. Vist URL /@@atct_migrator and check all Archetypes items for migration.

Then, I find the collection pagination (page #1 is working, but) not showing items for page #2.

[image: not showing items for page #2]

The issue remains if I create another new collection. How can I fix it?

Comment: Open an issue at https://github.com/plone/plone.app.contenttypes/issues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a bug in plone.app.contenttypes and is fixed by: https://github.com/plone/plone.app.contenttypes/commit/a54764f819afbdbc4001539f6244948a4248129b

Also see the discussion on github: https://github.com/plone/plone.app.contenttypes/issues/221